# SQL Server query for hierarchical group wise sum for the chart of accounts

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have created a query for displaying account name and balance as follows.

Table Structure is as follows.

```
Level      Account                Balance  AccountCode  ParentAccountCode

1      Revenue                          0           41         NULL
2      Direct Income                    0          411           41
3      Sales                            0         4111          411
4      Sales                            0        41111         4111
5      In Store Sales                 100       411111        41111
5      Online Sales                   200       411112        41111
2      Indirect Income                  0          412           41
3      Interest                         0         4121          412
4      Bank Interest                    0        41211         4121
5      Bank Interest A                400       412111        41211 
5      Bank Interest B                700       412112        41211
3      Other Income                     0         4122          412
4      Other Income                     0        41221         4122
5      Other Income                   900       412211        41221
```

All the above fields are from same table.

But only level 5 accounts have balance.

I want to write the sql query to show addition of accounts of child account in parent accounts hierarchically and level wise.

Expected result is as follows

```
Level      Account                              Balance

1         Revenue                                  2300
2         Direct Income                             300
3         Sales                                     300
4         Sales                                     300
5         In Store Sales                            100
5         Online Sales                              200
2         Indirect Income                          2000
3         Interest                                 1100
4         Bank Interest                            1100
5         Bank Interest A                           400
5         Bank Interest B                           700
3         Other Income                              900
4         Other Income                              900
5         Other Income                              900
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please give some details about the Table Structure

Comment: Could you show how the desired output should looks like?

Answer (score 2):

Edited to match your structure:

```
with AccountBalanceHierarchy as
(
-- root level
select AccountCode
     , ParentAccountCode
     , Account
     , 1 as [Level]
     , cast('-' + cast (AccountCode as nvarchar(10)) + '-' as nvarchar(100)) as Hierarchy -- build hierarchy in format -L0-L1-L2-...-Ln--
     , Balance 
  from AccountBalance 
 where ParentAccountCode is null
 union all
  -- recursive join on parent, building hierarchy
select CurrentLevel.AccountCode
     , CurrentLevel.ParentAccountCode
     , CurrentLevel.Account
     , ParentLevel.[Level]+1 as [Level]
     , cast(ParentLevel.Hierarchy + cast (CurrentLevel.AccountCode as nvarchar(10))+ '-' as nvarchar(100)) as Hierarchy
     , CurrentLevel.Balance
  from AccountBalance CurrentLevel
  join AccountBalanceHierarchy ParentLevel on CurrentLevel.ParentAccountCode = ParentLevel.AccountCode
)
select CurrentHierarchyLevel.[Level]
     , replicate('    ', CurrentHierarchyLevel.[Level]) + CurrentHierarchyLevel.Account as Account
     , sum(case when CurrentHierarchyLevel.Hierarchy = substring(ChildLevel.Hierarchy, 1, len(CurrentHierarchyLevel.Hierarchy)) then ChildLevel.Balance else 0 end)
  from AccountBalanceHierarchy as CurrentHierarchyLevel
 cross 
  join AccountBalanceHierarchy as ChildLevel
 group by CurrentHierarchyLevel.[Level], CurrentHierarchyLevel.Account,CurrentHierarchyLevel.Hierarchy
 order by CurrentHierarchyLevel.Hierarchy
```

**Explanation:**

In the hierarchy CTE, we build a hierarchy of your nodes starting with the root level (where ParentAccountCode is null) and then we join other levels through the ParentAccountCOde = AccountCode while increasing the Level.

In the CTE we also build a flat structure of your nodes, in a form of -L0-L1-...-Ln for each of the nodes. The root will have this structure as -41-, then its children with IDs 411 and 412 will have the structure -41-411- and -41-4112-, 411's child with code 4111 will be -41-411-4111-. Your AccountCodes actually make this unnecessary, because they match eachother, but I have a feeling they might not necessarily be the **true** IDs since you just edited your question a couple of times. The solution with building the structure like in the code makes this independed of IDs given to the accounts.

Then finally we select from the CTE and get the balance for all cross joining all the nodes and matching the generated flat structure of the children with the current structure. We know that the children of a given node will have the same beginning of the structure as the parent. Example following above: all children of root item 1 with structure -1- will have -1- at the beginning, e.g. -1-3-, -1-3-5-, -1-2-; or all children of -1-3-5- will have -1-3-5- at the beginning (e.g. -1-3-5-10). This is done in the SUM by using CASE statement - if the beginning of the structure matches (substring of the child structure is equal to the parent's structure), use the current_value for sum.

Here's the sqlfiddle with schema and query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/09ec8/1 and resulting data which matches your expected result:

```
Level       Account                                    Balance
----------- ------------------------------------------ ---------------------
1               Revenue                                2300,00
2                   Direct Income                      300,00
3                       Sales                          300,00
4                           Sales                      300,00
5                               In Store Sales         100,00
5                               Online Sales           200,00
2                   Indirect Income                    2000,00
3                       Interest                       1100,00
4                           Bank Interest              1100,00
5                               Bank Interest A        400,00
5                               Bank Interest B        700,00
3                       Other Income                   900,00
4                           Other Income               900,00
5                               Other Income           900,00
```